# Laravel WHERE AND CLAUSE not working properly

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, backend, where-clause

I want to update `t_bapr` with condition `t_prbk` and `t_item` but it doesn't work properly.

The datas something like this:

```
{
    "type": "success",
    "message": "Data updated successfully.",
    "data": [
        {
            "t_prbk": "SB1900003",
            "t_item": "         FCLADM31482BZ1700000",
            "t_bapr": "60.0"
        },
        {
            "t_prbk": "SB1900003",
            "t_item": "         FCLAHM43312K64N10100",
            "t_bapr": "60.0"
        },
        {
            "t_prbk": "SB1900003",
            "t_item": "         FCLAHM43312K64N10100",
            "t_bapr": "60.0"
        },
        {
            "t_prbk": "SB1900003",
            "t_item": "         FCLAHM-4331A-K2W -N002-IN",
            "t_bapr": "60.0"
        }
    ]
}
```

and then this is the controller:

```
public function priceBookUpdate(Request $request, $t_prbk, $t_item)
    {
        $request->validate([
            't_bapr' => 'integer'
        ]);

        $price_book = PriceBookTtdpcg031::where('t_prbk', $t_prbk)
                    ->where('t_item', $t_item)
                    ->firstOrFail();

        $price_book->t_bapr = $request->t_bapr;
        $price_book->save();

        $data = PriceBookTtdpcg031::select('t_prbk', 't_item', 't_bapr')
                ->where('t_prbk', 'SB1900003')
                ->get();

        return response()->json([
            'type' => 'success',
            'message' => trans('message.update_success'),
            'data' => $data
        ], 201);
    }
```

```
Route::post('/sales-price-update-pb/{t_prbk}/{t_item}', 'SalesPriceController@priceBookUpdate');
```

When I click update I want the `t_bapr` column value to change according to the `t_prbk` and `t_item` parameters that I specify. But the parameters used are only `t_prbk`.

I'm using laravel 6.0 and SQL Server.

Comment: I see in the controller, you only update the first $price_book with where condition $t_prbk and $t_item. And the data you return only check with `t_prbk`. I don't really understand what's your problem.

Comment: for the data return is only for check data that has been updated. i have problem that i want to update with condition $t_prbk and $t_item but condition $t_item not working properly, i think it's because of space in values data. i was tried with like, and str_replace to replace space in data values but still can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try in following way.

```
$price_book = PriceBookTtdpcg031::where('t_prbk', $t_prbk)
                    ->whereRaw('TRIM(t_item) = ?', [trim($t_item)])
                    ->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: still error, this is the error message:
`"message": "SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'. (SQL: select top 1 * from [ttdpcg031221] where [t_prbk] = SB1900003 and TRIM(t_item))"`